# Most efficient way to populate a set of UITextFields

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am creating an "account" view for a JSON API backed iOS app. I've got something like this to fill in all the fields based on API results (where `results` is an NSDictionary from the JSON):

```
self.nameField.text = [results objectForKey:@"name"];
self.emailField.text = [results objectForKey:@"email"];
self.websiteField.text = [results objectForKey:@"website"];
self.phoneField.text = [results objectForKey:@"phone"];
```

This works, but I get an error if any of the `results` are `NSNull`. I could wrap each one in an `if` statement, like so...

```
if (![[results objectForKey:@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    self.nameField.text = [results objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

...but it seems like there must be a less verbose and more efficient way to do this. I have about 10 fields to populate and 30 lines of code to do so seems ridiculous.

I know I could created a helper method for this, but surely Apple, or someone else, has already considered this? Is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FYI, you can use subscripting on an `NSDictionary`.  You don't have to write out `objectForKey:`.

To answer your explicit questions:

1. I don't think there's any helper method for this in the public iOS SDK.
2. As far as I know, there is no “more efficient way” than writing a helper method or function.

For example, you could write a `static inline` function in your `.m` file, or you could add a method to your class, or you could write a category on `UITextField` containing a `my_setTextSafely:` method, or you could write a category on `NSDictionary` containing a `my_stringForKey:` method.

Answer (score 3):

Write a little help method:

```
- (NSString *)textForKey:(NSString *)key {
    id val = results[key];
    if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return (NSString *)val;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

self.nameField.text = [self textForKey:@"name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the names of your text fields, you can name them after the fields in your dictionary and use key-value coding to write a few lines of magical code. For example,

In your view controller you could create the following text fields.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *websiteTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneTextField;
```

Then you could write a method to return the values of your keys.

```
- (NSArray *)keys
{
    return @[@"name", @"email", @"website", @"phone"];
}
```

.. and a simple way to grab the text field based on the key.

```
- (UITextField *)textFieldForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    return [self valueForKey:[key stringByAppendingString:@"TextField"]];
}
```

.. then you can write a method to grab the data from your dictionary, reacting properly to NSNull

```
- (NSString *)valueForKey:(NSString *)key inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    return dictionary[key] != [NSNull null] ? dictionary[key] : @"";
}
```

.. and put it in each text field automagically.

```
- (void)updateTextFields
{
    for (NSString *key in self.keys) 
    {
        [self textFieldForKey:key].text = [self valueForKey:key inDictionary:myDictionary];
    }
}
```

So long as you name each text field appropriately, all you have to do to handle more keys is add a new UITextField and a key to the keys method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tenary operator:

```
self.nameField.text = (results[@"name"] != [NSNull null]) ? results[@"name"] : @"";
```

Comment: `results[@"name"]` will always be non-nil.

Comment: @maddy, why will results[@"name"] always be nil? If the results dictionary doesn't contain a key @"name", it should indeed return nil.

Comment: @DuncanC I said "non-nil", not "nil". You can't put `nil` in an `NSDictionary`. As the OP states, it contains `NSNull` objects. Big difference.

Comment: @Kirsteins Your update was correct. You are back to the wrong answer again.

Comment: @maddy Oops, that was a type on my part. As to your reply, Hmm. I took the OPs post to mean that the results were nil, not that the dictionary contained NSNull for that key. I know lots of people who use NULL and nil interchangeably. Perhaps we should ask for clarification from the OP.

Comment: @DuncanC Look at the OP's code. They are talking about getting an error. This is because of the `NSNull`. You can't assign an `NSNull` to the `text` property of a `UILabel`.